# Can not create app using create-react-app, after a tried some solutions

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

my npm vision: 6.9.0,
my node vision: 10.16.3
I reinstalled the npm and node
I tried npm cache clean --force
Finally, I still get this:

[My codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QupkF.png)

Comment: Try `npx create-react-app my-app`

Comment: I tried, but nothing changed

Comment: try with docker !

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. Put you code inside the question, not as a link.

Comment: It seems that your problem may be related to your username containing an space. Take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6512) and check if any of the provided solutions work for you!